# How do you use the Silex form service provider with Symfony's PhpEngine templating?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Can anyone provide a working example of how to use Silex's "form" service provider with the symfony2 PhpEngine templating?

I've gotten the PhpEngine templating working in Silex no problem, but I can't find any of examples of how to render the form in Silex with anything other than twig.

When I try to render the form in Silex with the PhpEngine, and following the instructions on the symfony2 page like this:

```
<?php echo $view['form']->form($form) ?>
```

I get the following error:

```
The helper "form" is not defined.
```

(That helper, BTW, seems to be part of the symfony framework, and lives in neither the "form" nor "templating" components.)

If anyone has a working example of how to do this, with or without that missing helper, I'd be much appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution here:

https://github.com/bschussek/standalone-forms/blob/2.1%2Bphp/web/index.php

The reason I didn't see it at first is because the example for using the PHP rendering engine is in a separate branch.